# How to override and change context menu icon in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

[Image for your reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dY2sn.png)

when we right click in project explorer, the list occurs which is also known as context menu. I want to replace these icons in this menu with other icons of my choice. How can i do this ?

I want to replace the context menu icons of eclipse ide  with icons of my choice

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there is no mechanism for doing that.

Comment: Do you mean the icons literally, or which wizards are shown in the menu?

Comment: @nitind yes, I mean icons only